# Connect from 3G dongle (eth1) to wlan0

Tags: bridge

I trying to make the following work on my Raspberry Pi (Running Linux):
I have a 3G dongle connected that has a static IP adress and allows incomming traffic, it is presented as interface eth1. I also have a wifi dongle that is connected to a hardware device which needs to be configured. The hardware device will setup an Access point, that is used for configuration, much like the interface used by routers ect.

How do I reach the hardware device from my PC via the internet ?

My PC --(Internet)--> 3G Dongle --(eth1)--> Raspberry Pi --(wlan0)--> hardware device (AP)

I tried using the bridge-utils, but is says that it cannot bridge to wlan0.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need bridging for this.  There are several ways to do this but one of the simplest is the `iptables`' `-j MASQUERADE` target.  You need to:

1. enable IP forwarding (e.g. by running `sysctl -p` with the line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`)
2. enable masquerading for packets forwarded to the eth1 interface:

```sh
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

This will masqerade outbound connections from your wlan to the internet.

3. To forward inbound port 80 and port 443 (http and https) connections from the internet to your web server on IP address 10.0.1.184 as mentioned in your comment, you need a DNAT rule in the PREROUTING table:

```sh
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth1 -m multiport \
    --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to 10.0.1.184
```

(This can be on one line.  I've split it with a `\` here to avoid having a horizontal scrollbar on this site)

If you have firewall rules (or, e.g., a default deny policy) that would otherwise block forwarding of the packets, you may also need an ACCEPT rule in your FORWARD table.   Firewall rules to block access to your wlan aren't, of course, strictly necessary here because 10.0.0.0/8 is a private network that isn't routed on the internet.

```sh
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth1 -o wlan0 -d 10.0.1.184 -m multiport 
    --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank you. My hardware device's access point will give IP addresses in the 10.0.1.x net, so the wlan0 interface has IP of example: 10.0.1.184, and the 3G dongle has an static IP address in some other IP range. So do I just need to type the IP address of my 3G dongle in my browser, and it will hit the webpage on 10.0.1.184 ?

Comment: No, the masquerade allows outbound connections from your wlan to the internet via eth1.   To do inbound port forwarding, you need to do DNAT.

Comment: Okay thank you, how do I do that ?
(Sorry for me being a total noob)